# Using a Plugin to call the Main fuctions

Tags: methodology, plugins

I have a program that uses OMR to scan a photo of a "scoresheet", and give a result. Its functionality is:

- Scan one photo
- Compare with database for which "template" to use, identify the coordinates for blocks, etc., "correct" and "incorrect" answers (both for which one(s) are correct/incorrect, and the values assigned to each)
- Return a report of the scores, based on the above information.

What I have built is a series of plugins that:

- Which database to use
- Contains which template to use
- Contains any possible modifiers to each "correct" or "incorrect" answers
- Can support a list of results.

The problem I'm having is whether or not the best practice is to allow the plugin to call method(s) within the Main program.

So, the current program flow I am looking to build is:

1. Program Starts (Main), builds a list of Plugin Instances and populates a dropdown for the user to select.
2. User selects which Scoring plugin to use.
3. Plugin loads its Form, and the Main Form is set to invisible (to allow the Application Environment to remain open).
4. User then selects one or more images to scan
5. Plugin then runs a "foreach" loop on the images, and passes in the photo, database, template, and modifiers to the Main
   5a. Main runs through its methodology to calculate the score for the image, passes back the result
   5b. Plugin builds a model for that result
6. Once the plugin has received a report for each image, displays that report in a format specific to the plugin's function (e.g. sport/test/etc).
7. Once the user has finished with the Plugin from, the Plugin calls the Main Application, to either rebuild the List of Plugin Instances, or Close the program.

Now, since the Plugins are driving the functionality of the overall program, but they themselves don't do much, the line between which one is the Main app and the Plugin kind of blurs. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Downvoter(s), the OP **cannot read your mind**. If you have some critics, please state it clearly.

Comment: Sounds to me like each plugin is attempting to be the run loop. Lift it out and have the plugin provide strategies for each of the holes which the main program doesn't understand. EG a filter strategy for selecting inputs, an argument strategy for selecting various arguments for the core processor.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach here is to solve this by some event mechanics:

- the plugin does not set the main form to "invisible", it does not "rebuild the list of plugin instances" directly, and it does not close the main form directly
- instead, it emits an event, for example, whenever it has completed a certain task
- the main form has to register some event handler or callback for the event, and performs the required actions on itself.

That way, you keep the logic for the main program in the main program, where it belongs, and still allow certain interactions between "main" and "plugin" in an interwoven fashion.

What looks strange to me in your question: you wrote

> ... series of plugins that:
>
> - Which database to use
> - Contains which template to use
> - Contains any possible modifiers to each "correct" or "incorrect" answers
> - Can support a list of results.

None of these functionalities requires the plugin to have a Form itself. It sounds your plugin implementing essentially something like the strategy pattern, no less, no more.

But then you also wrote

> Plugin loads its Form [... and ...] runs a "foreach" loop on the images

and that looks suspiciously like something which should be part of the main program, and not of the plugin itself - a generic form which works as a container for different plugins, and which controls the processing. So there is where I would suggest taking a closer look at your design. If you can keep the UI functionality out of the plugins, this may lead to a clearer separation of concerns and avoid duplicating very similar form code between different plugins.